# Calculating the distance between points and parts of a underlying raster set

Tags: qgis, raster, distance

I need your help with a calculation of the distance between points (cities in this case) and forest (raster data). [image: points and forestcover of Liberia]

Is there a possibility to collate to every city the distance to the nearest forest area?